# Can you extract the nth-child value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list of an indeterminate number of child elements:

```
<ul>
    <li ID="alpha"></li>
    <li ID="bravo"></li>
    ...
    <li ID="hotel"></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

If I were to click on any of these elements, would it be possible to find out which child number they are in the list, and pass that value to a variable?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, the jQuery index method will give you that info:

```
$(this).index(); // will return the index relative to its other siblings.
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.4,

```
$('li').click(function(){
   alert( $(this).index() );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you can use the .index() method. Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Gy88N/

Code follows

```
<ul>
    <li ID="alpha">Item 1</li>
    <li ID="bravo">Item 2</li>
    <li ID="hotel">Item 3</li>
    <li ID="hotel2">Item 4</li>
    <li ID="hotel3">Item 5</li>
</ul>


$('ul li').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).index())
})
```